# Is it possible to extrapolate data for a 3d-plot in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, plot, calculations

I am having several measurements to plot and would like to use something like a 3d surface from `pgfplots`. I am having a frame as outer border and a grid as measurement raster. The measured values are taken in the middle of each grid cell. When plotting the whole surface, I would like to extrapolate the data until the frames outer borders in order to fill the whole thing with the surface.

Here is what I have for so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,grid style={black, thin}
    ,y label style={rotate=-90}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            ,colorbar
            ,view={0}{90}
            ,xmin=0
            ,xmax=3910
            ,ymin=0
            ,ymax=2040
            ,width=391pt
            ,height=204pt
            ,grid=major
            ,xlabel=Width $b_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
            ,ylabel=Height $h_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
        ]
        \addplot3[%
            ,surf
            ,shader=interp
        ] file {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and `data.dat` looks like:

```
85  1955    0.97
255 1955    1.86
425 1955    2.44
595 1955    2.23
765 1955    2.17
935 1955    2.35
1105    1955    2.21
1275    1955    2.53
1445    1955    2.58
1615    1955    2.64
1785    1955    2.6
1955    1955    2.03
2125    1955    2.5
2295    1955    2.32
2465    1955    2.22
2635    1955    2
2805    1955    1.59
2975    1955    2.23
3145    1955    2.18
3315    1955    2.07
3485    1955    2.38
3655    1955    2.48
3825    1955    1.42

85  1785    1.3
255 1785    1.41
...
```

So I need to get values for all `x = 0` and `y = 0` points. As `pgfplots` is able to interpolate, maybe, it is able to extrapolate as well.

That's what it looks like:

[image]

Two extra points:

- I would like to get the grid (not the ticks) onto the measurement raster, say, each 170 mm
- I would like to get the colormap labeled with `speed $v$ in \si{\metre\per\second}`

Comment: Why not making the border smaller?

Comment: @percusse Because that border is the actual frame of the measurements. I would change the dimensions. My first measurement is at 85 85 but there is also speed in the very corner. I will set all walls to zero now, which will be more correct than an extrapolation I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the main question:

`pgfplots` comes without builtin support for extrapolations.

You would need to compute them by means of an external product, maybe `octave` or `matlab`.

Answer (score 4):

(Partial solution) I don't know about such feature, I'm sorry. But I can help you with those two extra tasks. Here we go.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,grid style={black, thin}
    ,y label style={rotate=-90}}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
85  1955    0.97
255 1955    1.86
425 1955    2.44
595 1955    2.23
765 1955    2.17
935 1955    2.35
1105    1955    2.21
1275    1955    2.53
1445    1955    2.58
1615    1955    2.64
1785    1955    2.6
1955    1955    2.03
2125    1955    2.5
2295    1955    2.32
2465    1955    2.22
2635    1955    2
2805    1955    1.59
2975    1955    2.23
3145    1955    2.18
3315    1955    2.07
3485    1955    2.38
3655    1955    2.48
3825    1955    1.42
85  1785    1.3
255 1785    1.41 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            ,colorbar
            ,view={0}{90}
            ,xmin=0
            ,xmax=3910
            ,ymin=0
            ,ymax=2040
            ,width=391pt
            ,height=204pt
            ,grid=major
            ,xlabel=Width $b_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
            ,ylabel=Height $h_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
,xtick={0,170,...,3910}
,ytick={0,170,...,2040}
,tick style={black}
,x tick label style={rotate=90}
        ]
        \addplot3[
            ,surf, 
            ,shader=interp
        ] file {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\node[xshift=2mm, yshift=4.5mm, rotate=90] at (current bounding box.east){Speed $v$ in \si{\metre\per\second}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** We can extend our example by using major and minor ticks to get an effect that grid is more frequent than its labels. I have added another 3D plot with two blank points to control minimum and maximum on the z axis, it affects the colormap.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\SendSettingsToPgf
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,grid style={black, thin}
    ,y label style={rotate=-90}}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
85  1955    0.97
255 1955    1.86
425 1955    2.44
595 1955    2.23
765 1955    2.17
935 1955    2.35
1105    1955    2.21
1275    1955    2.53
1445    1955    2.58
1615    1955    2.64
1785    1955    2.6
1955    1955    2.03
2125    1955    2.5
2295    1955    2.32
2465    1955    2.22
2635    1955    2
2805    1955    1.59
2975    1955    2.23
3145    1955    2.18
3315    1955    2.07
3485    1955    2.38
3655    1955    2.48
3825    1955    1.42
85  1785    1.3
255 1785    1.41 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            ,colorbar
            ,view={0}{90}
            ,xmin=0
            ,xmax=3910
            ,ymin=0
            ,ymax=2040
            ,width=391pt
            ,height=204pt
            ,grid=minor
            ,xlabel=Width $b_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
            ,ylabel=Height $h_\mathrm{frame}$ in \si{\milli\metre}
,minor xtick={0,170,...,5000}
,minor ytick={0,170,...,5000}
,xtick={0,500,...,5000}
,ytick={0,500,...,5000}
,tick style={black}
%,x tick label style={rotate=90}
        ]
\addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {data.dat};
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 3)};
    \end{axis}
\node[xshift=2mm, yshift=4.5mm, rotate=90] at (current bounding box.east){Speed $v$ in \si{\metre\per\second}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. If you know a way, just to multiply the grid lines, but to write ticks every 500 mm, that would be cool.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Oh yes, we can achive that by adding minor ticks, please, see an edit.

Comment: Great, if I may ask one more thing. Can you fix the range of the colormap? So that each plot shows from 0 to 3 m/s?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Adding two blank points `0 0 0` and `0 0 3` into your data file directly would be considered as a dirty and dangerous trick. It would affect the calculations from you data and even plotting. I was hoping that `zmin=0, zmax=3` is what we need, but it is not providing expected effect in this case. Therefore, I added another plot by using `\addplot3[surf] coordinates {(0, 0, 0) (0, 0, 3)};` which is becoming invisible with so few points and the `surf` plot type in use.